# How do I change the root password on my Synology Rackstation?

Tags: passwords, nas, synology

Synology's OS doesn't seem to have a `passwd` command, and I have been unable to change my Root user's password using the `synouser` command:

`MyNas > synouser --setpw root hunter2
Lastest SynoErr=[user_set.c:1040]
synouser.c:616 SYNOUserSet failed. synoerr=[0x1D00]`

I found [this thread](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=86671) with the same error message, but I don't want to install `sudo` and `passwd` from Optware on this NAS.

[This thread](https://primalcortex.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/synology-dsm-root-password-for-ssh/) suggests rebooting the Synology, and I tried that in desperation, but I get the same error after it finishes starting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to change the root password by changing the admin password with the same command.

`synouser --setpw admin hunter2`

Once I had changed the admin account's password, I could log in as root or as admin with the new password. I had thought it was a coincidence that the two accounts had the same password, but they are apparently joined together.

Comment: Actually I cannot log in as "root" but I can log in as "admin" then run `sudo su -` to become "root". The sudo password is identical to the password of the "admin" user. Doing just `su -` from the admin account and does not work for any password. Indeed `/etc/shadow` shows that "root" doesn't have a password in the first place. As `/etc/sudoers` contains `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`, running `sudo su -`will indeed demand the "admin" password. It all looks Ubuntish.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer, I no longer have access to that Synology machine, so I can't tell you with certainty what version of the software it was running, but I think it was 5.1. I didn't have `sudo` or `su` and didn't want to install it from the optional repos, which was what set me down the path of mucking with the root password in the first place.

If it was up to me, I'd block root logins and make everyone `sudo su` the way you describe.

Answer (score -2):

All seems unnecessary to me but heigh ho. I resolved this after banging my head on brickwall for some time by setting the admin password through the web interface, ssh to the synology as admin, sudoing to the root id using bash and then running synouser --passwd root

Comment: OP appears to explicitly state they do NOT want to install sudo or passwd. OP also has answered their own question and posted the answer here.